# How to trigger an event as soon as we launch the view in SWT

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, composite

I have an RCP application where I am creating a view which invokes an instance of the composite.Now my problem is I want to trigger one event as soon as I show the view/composite in the screen.

I tried with `addFocusListner(),addMouseTrackListener(),addMouseListner()`but unfortunately none of the them gets the control as I move my mouse pointer around the view.Is there any way we can solve it?

Comment: Trigger what event? Just put your code in the `createPartControl`

Comment: createPartControl() will be called automatically when I try to launch the view.But my objective here is to trigger once I move my mouse around the view /composite after the launch. I want to set one flag to true after the launch when I try to move my mouse.

Comment: If you have other controls in the Composite they will be getting the mouse events. You might be able to do something with `Display.addFilter` but it gets messy.

Comment: Also note that the mouse being over your view does not make it the active part (or focussed). There are proper APIs to determine when your view is the active view.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the control you have used to create view and add selection listener on it.

for example if treeViewer is used to create that view then:

```
treeViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(element),true);
```

Ensure selection by this `treeViewer.getControl.setFocus();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger an event after your view is in focus/launch then you should add a listener to that view e.g `IPartListener2`for that you need to create a class and implement `IPartListener2` interface. you will get more information [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_what_view_or_editor_is_selected%3F)

Also if you want only using mouse event then you need to add `MouseMoveListener` to your view so when mouse pointer on your when `mouseMove` will call.
e.g. `control.addMouseMoveListener(this);`